# Use DI to instantiate a service with a dynamic parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, service-provider

I have a class with below constructor:

```
public MyClass(SomeRequiredService srs, string someRandomInput)
{

}
```

How can I register `MyClass` with DI but with an option to pass a *different* `someRandomInput` each time i need to get an instance of `MyClass`?

or

With below constructor how can I get access to registered services or `IServiceProvider` in `MyClass` ctor while having a *dynamic* parameter in constructor?

```
public MyClass(string someRandomInput)
{
    // how access a registered service here using DI?
}
```

Comment: _"How can I get access to IServiceProvider or other required services in MyClass? (don't want to instantiate MyClass manually and passing parameters)"_ - Using `IServiceProvider` as a ctor param is a bad idea (and makes it impossible to instantiate your type in unit-testing or non-container scenarios) - though you could provide an in-`class` `public static` factory of convenience, or at least an alternative ctor overload (don't forget to apply `[ActivatorUtilitiesConstructor]`)

Comment: If you can try to prevent the situation by changing your design, because [mixing runtime data with design time dependencies during object construction leads to unfortunate complications](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I register MyClass with DI but with an option to pass someRandomInput each time i need to get an instance?

Assuming `someRandomInput` only needs to be specified once, then you can do this in an `implementationFactory:` in your service registration:

```
IConfiguration cfg = ...

//

services
    .AddSingleton<MyClass>( implementationFactory: ( IServiceProvider sp ) =>
        new MyClass(
            srs            : sp.GetRequiredService<SomeRequiredService>(),
            someRandomInput: cfg.GetString("Foobars")
        )
    );
```

The same works for `AddTransient` and `AddScoped` - the catch being that they'll all use whatever value you pass into `someRandomInput` in your factory - though your factory method itself could also use the `IServiceProvider` to get *another* service as a source for those values.

---

More generalised, here's two approaches:

### Option 1: Define an interface that represents your services' data-dependency

```
public interface IFoobarsServiceRequisite
{
    String GetNextStringValue();
}

public class FoobarsService
{
    public FoobarsService( SomeRequiredService srs, IFoobarsServiceRequisite requisiteData )
    {
    }
}
```

...then you'd register some implementation of that `Requisite` service interface.

### Option 2: *Not-quite-as-bad-as* `AbstractSingletonProxyFactoryBean`

([In case anyone missed the reference](https://seajug.yahoogroups.narkive.com/PRMOoEvk/everything-that-s-wrong-with-java-in-a-single-class))

```
services
    .AddSingleton<SomeRequiredService>()
    .AddSingleton<ISomeRandomStringSource,DefaultSomeRandomStringSource>()
    .AddSingleton<IFoobarsServiceFactory,DefaultFoobarsServiceFactory>()
    .AddTransient<FoobarsService>( sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IFoobarsServiceFactory>().CreateFoobar() );


//

public interface IFoobarsServiceFactory
{
    FoobarsService CreateFoobar();
}

public class DefaultFoobarsServiceFactory : IFoobarsServiceFactory
{
    private readonly SomeRequiredService     srs;
    private readonly ISomeRandomStringSource src;

    public DefaultFoobarsServiceFactory(
        SomeRequiredService srs,
        ISomeRandomStringSource src
    )
    {
        this.srs = srs;
        this.src = src;
    }

    public FoobarsService CreateFoobar()
    {
        return new FoobarsService( this.srs, this.src.GetNextValue() );
    }
}

public class FoobarsService
{
    public FoobarsService( SomeRequiredService srs, String someRandomValue )
    {
    }
}
```

and it's factories all the way down...

---

I was surprised that MEDI still lacks a standardised `IServiceFactory` interface to handle the awkward edge-cases that need more factory-logic than a simple `sp =>` lambda, but which don't *need* to explicitly call their `.CreateService()` methods in application code - especially as EF already has its own `IDbContextFactory` type.

### Update: Option 3: Factory-service-with-caller-provided-args

After clarifying things in the comments, I think the OP is after something like this:

- The `FoobarServiceFactory` (or an `interface` thereof) is a normal Singleton service which *carries* the `FoobarService` dependencies - but also allows/requires the consumers of `FoobarServiceFactory` to provide their own arguments for when they want to get an instance of `FoobarService`, like so:

```
services.AddSingleton<IFoobarServiceFactory,FoobarServiceFactory>()

//

public interface IFoobarServiceFactory // Note that this interface is entirely optional: you could just register `FoobarServiceFactory` as a service.
{
    FoobarsService CreateFoobar( String callerProvidedData );
}

public class FoobarServiceFactory: IFoobarServiceFactory
{
    private readonly SomeRequiredService srs;

    public DefaultFoobarsServiceFactory( SomeRequiredService srs )
    {
        this.srs = srs;
    }

    public FoobarsService CreateFoobar( String callerProvidedData )
    {
        return new FoobarService( this.srs, callerProvidedData );
    }
}

public class FoobarService
{
    public FoobarService( SomeRequiredService srs, String someRandomValue )
    {
        // etc
    }
}
```

Used like so:

```
public class SomeConsumer
{
    private readonly IFoobarServiceFactory fbFactory;

    public SomeConsumer( IFoobarServiceFactory fbFactory )
    {
        this.fbFactory = fbFactory;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        String someRandomString = Math.Random() > 0.5 ? "abc" : "0xdeadbeef";
        
        FoobarService svc = this.fbFactory.Create( someRandomString );
        // do stuff with `svc`
    }
}
```

An alternative implementation of `IFoobarServiceFactory` could use `IServiceProvider`, if it isn't possible to retain a long-life'd (or unbound lifetime) for `SomeRequiredService` (and IMO, this is the only acceptable reason to ever need `IServiceProvider` as an actual dependency (other than breaking cycles in dependency graphs, ofc):

```
public class AltFoobarServiceFactory : IFoobarServiceFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider sp;

    public AltFoobarServiceFactory( IServiceProvider sp )
    {
        this.sp = sp;
    }

    public FoobarsService CreateFoobar( String callerProvidedData )
    {
        // `ActivatorUtilities` is useful! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0
        return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<FoobarsService>( sp, callerProvidedData );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but your assumption is not correct. Main point of question is "option to pass someRandomInput each time i need an instance"

Comment: @HamidZ Please edit your post with a practical example so that we can see what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I tried my best to clarify more. i changed title too, i guess that was not much related to the problem.

Comment: @HamidZ You just need a factory-service - your `String someRandomInput` value would be a normal method parameter on your factory's `MyService Create( String someRandomInput )` method, while the factory itself contains the `IServiceProvider` - there's really no other way: with DI everything has to be _explicit_ and passed through the stack _or_ by using factories - the (unworkable) alternative is revert back to how people did things around ~2005 with _mutable `static` state_, which only causes severe problems down-the-line. **Just learn to embrace constructors and factories**.

Comment: You're right. I thought there might be a way to tell DI to accept a custom parameter each time or maybe some static access to registered services but likely no way yet. Can you update your answer with factory way so I could accept it?

Comment: @HamidZ That's what the `DefaultFoobarsServiceFactory` in my answer is - but I'll make a variation now.

Comment: @HamidZ I've updated my answer with a third option which I think is what you're describing?

Answer (score 0):

You can register your service with custom factory method

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<TestService>(s =>
    new TestService(s.GetRequiredService<SomeDependency>(), "Ololo"));
```